# Browser Caching for Logged in Users

Tags: login, cache, members

We've run into sort of a quirky problem with browser caching that I'm having a hard time finding an answer to.

When users log in to the site, if they go to a page they have already visited, it will show them as still logged out unless they refresh the page. If they go to a new page, one they haven't visited, there aren't any problems. This is also something that is happening sometimes when they add products to their cart.

Right now, we are using Autoptimize and Redis Caching, but the problem happens even when those are turned off. There isn't any other caching in place, and this seems to be a problem that has just surfaced recently.

Is there anyway we can force the browser to clear it's cache when a user logs in or adds a product to their cart?

Comment: That sure is odd! If you're sending them back to the page they came from, you could add a bit of a query string, like `?reload`, to tell the browser to get the page fresh. But that wouldn't reload every page, just that one.

Comment: It's actually just when they click back to one of the previous pages they are on. I've got the server techs looking into it, but they are suggesting that Woocommerce might have its own caching, but that's not really something I've run into before.

Comment: I have never heard of WooCommerce having it's own caching.  Autoptimize is one of the first things I remove when a client explains that they have been working themselves or with a previous developer to make their site perform better and aren't getting anywhere.  It's a 'one size fits all' approach and often adds problems if a site is even remotely complex.  I say you remove that and get your server techs to focus on the Redis Caching and Server-Side caching - you should also get them to exclude WooCommerce pages from caching because the problem you describe could cause issues for shoppers.